# Drawing a star on Python using "drawStar"

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have been writing a small code to have my turtle (t) drawing a star. I need to stay within the general perimeters of the code I have, but I would like someone to take a look and see what is going wrong. I am a new programmer, so bear with me.

```
import turtle

def drawStar(n, l):
    """Get turtle t to draw a star with n sides at l length"""
    for i in range(n):
        t.forward(l)
        t.left(36)
        t.forward(l)
        t.left(36)

drawStar(5, 100)

wn.exitonclick()
```

It says that the problem is on line 6 (drawStar(5, 100))

Comment: `t` is undefined.

Comment: I can't get some of these things to go on separate lines on the question. I even tried to edit it. Please excuse this.

Comment: What is the Python compiler telling you the error is?

Comment: import turtle
t=turtle

def drawStar(n, l):
    """Get turtle t to draw a star with n sides at l length"""
    for i in range(n):
        t.left(144)
        t.forward(l)
        t.left(144)
        t.forward(l)
       
drawStar(5, 100)


This is what I got now and it works! Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming you have a separate file called `turtle.py` where the problem is originating.  Can you post the actual error you're getting from this file?  (By the way, you can use `import turtle as t` to alias the turtle module without having to say `t = turtle` - it's a little cleaner.)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the syntax error discussed, you have a logic error.  Consider your `t.left(36)` statement, or later `t.left(144)` statement.  The angle passed is actually a function of `n` and making it a constant as you have means this routine only works for one value of `n`.  Consider:

```
drawStar(7, 100)
```

You don't get a seven pointed star, just some portion of a (duplicated) five pointed star.  Which is not what your docstring claims about `n`.  If we instead do:

```
import turtle

def drawStar(n, l):
    """Get turtle to draw a star with n sides of l length"""

    for _ in range(n):
        turtle.forward(l)
        turtle.left(2 * 360 / n)  # calculate the angle

drawStar(7, 100)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

We can still get our five pointed star if we want but we can also get a seven pointed star:

[image]

Unfortunately, this logic only works for odd values of `n`.  Even values give us back regular polygons of `n / 2` sides.  We need a different formula to generate stars with an even number of points...

Answer (score 0):

The issue that `t` is undefined. If `t` is supposed to invoke some method in from the `turtle` module directly, use:

```
import turtle as t
```